# Windows-1252? encoding issue with html entities

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, html-entities, windows-1252

I have inherited a database which at some point has has a serious character set issue. I think that it was originally Windows-1252, but has been saved as UTF-8 and then non-ASCII characters have been convereted to decimal HTML entities. Examples:

```
&#195;“Flaithearta Mair&#195;&#169;ad &amp; Arthur
```

which should be:

```
ÓFlaithearta Mairéad & Arthur
```

AND

```
Coyne P&#195;&#161;draic
```

which should be:

```
Coyne Pádraic
```

Does anyone know how this may be salvaged?

**N.B. Please do not edit this post to improve formatting, by doing so you changed the actual data.**

Comment: Are you sure it was Win-1252 and not Latin1? MySQL default encoding used to be Latin1 so a database that's old enough might still have these kinds of relics

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what the original encoding was. I guessed it was Win-1252 as I've had a similar issue with that.

Comment: Of course, HTML numeric entities are Unicode codepoints—but not here. Translate named entities to their Windows-1252 encoding. Translate numeric "entities" as decimal representations of Windows-1252 encoding. This yields the UTF-8 encoding of the string.

Comment: I'll give that a go later today.